# perl unexpected split behaviour

Tags: regex, perl, split

I'm trying to write down a perl script which will be able to distinguish between the different labels of my drives to a specific one and then do something in that specific drive.
I am running Active Perl 5.16.3.1603 on a windows XP computer.

Here is what I wrote:

```
use strict;
$_ = `fsutil fsinfo drives`;
my @drives = split;
my @labels;
for (@drives)
{
    push @labels, `label $_`;
}
for (@labels)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
```

The for loop at the end is a print check.
I get nothing as result. I tried to check it in another way:

```
use strict;
$_ = `fsutil fsinfo drives`;

print;
print "\n";
print join "\n", split;
```

My result is:

```
Drives: C:\ D:\ E:\ G:\

Drives:
C:\ D:\ E:\ G:\
```

Why does split act not the way it should?
I tried to do `split " "`, `split / /` and `split /\s+/`.
They all end up with the same output.

If someone knows why it happens and how to make it go away, please share.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://eval.in/91580 looks ok.

Comment: When I tried to manually put the string in $_ it worked.
$_ = "Drives: C:\\ D:\\ E:\\ G:\\"

Comment: Do a hex dump of the output of `fsutil fsinfo drives` to verity that you're getting actual space characters.

Comment: This works fine on Windows 7. Try this on a command line `perl -MData::Dumper -e"++$Data::Dumper::Useqq; print Dumper $_ = \`fsutil fsinfo drives\`"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hexdump - as advised by DavidO

```
00000000h: 0D 0A 44 72 69 76 65 73 3A 20 41 3A 5C 00 43 3A ; ..Drives: A:\.C:
00000010h: 5C 00 44 3A 5C 00 45 3A 5C 00 4D 3A 5C 00 0D 0A ; \.D:\.E:\.M:\...
```

shows that you get more (leading/trailing CrLf) and other (00 instead of 20) whitespace than you probably expected (tested under Win XP).

So to get a list of drive letters, a **positive** regular expression may be a better approach:

```
$ my $res = `fsutil fsinfo drives`;

Drives: A:\ C:\ D:\ E:\ M:\

$ $res =~ /\b\w:/g;
$ARRAY1 = [
            'A:',
            'C:',
            'D:',
            'E:',
            'M:'
          ];
```

**Update wrt comment:**

1. A [hexdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) gives you a clear view of binary data; I used it to show what you really get when you call fsutil.
2. I mentioned XP, because I can't rule out that fsutil returns a string with different delimiters on other versions of windows.
3. By using a regular expression that cuts what you want (drive letters) instead of what may lurk in between, I tried to propose a solution that works even when Mr. Gates changes the zeros to spaces, tabs, or ", ".
4. Could you provide a link that explaines the meaning of "other stuff" to the uninitiated?

Comment: It's amazing (though not unbelievable) the output would be so dirty, and that the "dirt" is so poorly documented: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Your solution works.  
But what is hex dump?  
Could that mean that other stuff won't work as expected on windows xp?